# Why does the this scope change when calling from a template or watcher?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-composition-api

With regards to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61653929/function-not-recognized-by-the-new-vue-composition-api/61654088#61654088) which contains all the code, I'm wondering why this works fine:

```js
<template>
  <q-drawer
    @mouseover="setMiniState(false)"
    @mouseout="setMiniState(true)"
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const miniState = ref(true)

    function setMiniState(state) {
      console.log('setMiniState widht is ', this.$q.screen.width)
    }

    return {
      miniState, setMiniState
    }
  }
})
```

But this does not:

```js
    function setMiniState(state) {
      console.log('setMiniState widht is ', this.$q.screen.width)
    }

    watch('$q.screen.width', () => setMiniState())
```

When the watcher is called the variable `$q` becomes `undefined`, this is not the case when the same function is called from the template. It seems like the `this` scope is changing in the way that the function `setMiniState` is called.

**Workaround 1**

Check in the function `setMiniState` if the argument `width` is available:

```js
<template>
  <q-drawer
    @mouseover="setMiniState(false)"
    @mouseout="setMiniState(true)"
</template>

function setMiniState(state, width) {
  let screenWidth = ''
  if (!width) {
    screenWidth = this.$q.screen.width
  } else {
    screenWidth = width
  }
  console.log('setMiniState this is ', screenWidth)
}

watch('$q.screen.width', (width) => setMiniState(undefined, width))
```

**Workaround 2**

Always send `state` and `width` arguments:

```js
<template>
  <q-drawer
    @mouseover="setMiniState(false, $q.screen.width)"
    @mouseout="setMiniState(true, $q.screen.width)"
</template>

function setMiniState(state, width) {
  console.log('setMiniState this is ', width)
}

watch('$q.screen.width', (width) => setMiniState(undefined, width))
```

I'm new to javaScript and trying to understand what is happening. Thank you for your help and or suggestion on how to best handle a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write `'$q.screen.width'`?

Try this:

```
watch(() => this.$q.screen.width, setMiniState)
```